# How should I write this Java function recursively?

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I'm trying to write the Java code below recursively:

```
public static int count(String word) {
    int numValue = 0;
    int length = word.length();
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String letter = (word.substring(0 + i,1 + i));
        numValue = numValue + alpha.indexOf(letter) + 1;
    }
    return numValue;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(count("abc"));
}
```

The function returns the sum of the index of each letter in the input string parameter.

I'm attempting to write this same code recuersively, can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

```
public static int count(int numValue, int i, String word) {
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if( i >= word.length()){
        return numValue;
    }
    else{
        String letter = (word.substring(0 + i,1 + i));
        numValue = numValue + alpha.indexOf(letter) + 1;
        count(numValue, i=i+1, word);
    }
    return numValue;
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(count(0,0, "abc"));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be recursive if it can be iterative? Usually it is faster to use a loop than all these recursive calls...

Comment: Your recursive function never stores or does anything with the value from the recursive call

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be just shrink the string again and again.

```
public static int count(String word) {
    if (word.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    final String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return alpha.indexOf(word.charAt(0)) + count(word.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change this function to be recursive, you would ideally use divide and conquer approach which is rather easy to implement. I will present it in a simple and verbose way so that you can see the steps clearly.

```
public static int count(String word) {
    int numValue = 0;
    int length = word.length();
    if(length > 1)
    {
        String substring1 = word.substring(0, length/2);
        String substring2 = word.subtring(length/2 + 1, length);
        numValue += count(substring1);
        numValue += count(substring2);
        return numValue;
    }
    else 
    {
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        return alpha.indexOf(word) + 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(count("abc"));
}
```

I suppose you are doing this as an exercise to teach yourself recursiveness - if not, you may want to think whether it is not better for you to just use the iterative approach instead of recursiveness.

Comment: This won't compile as "letter" appears out of nowhere in your else clause.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I made a typo. I edited it - thanks for poinitng that out :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `numValue` is of type `int`. So it doesnt get changed in the calling method, wenn you pass it to another method and change it in there. This means, the line `count(numValue, i=i+1, word);` basically does nothing.

You can correct the method by returning the result of the recursive call (Since you return in the `if`, `else` is not needed):

```
public static int count(int numValue, int i, String word) {
    String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    if( i >= word.length()){
        return numValue;
    }
    String letter = (word.substring(0 + i,1 + i));
    numValue = numValue + alpha.indexOf(letter) + 1;
    return count(numValue, i=i+1, word);
}
```

This is the reason, why your function does not work properly. The answer provided by timrau is a nicer solution for the recursion.